# Postfix completely ignores relayhost setting in main.cf

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-14.04

I am having trouble sending email to my relay host. All mail is being directly delivered.

`postconf -n`:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination =
myhostname = webserver.example.com
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = smtp.example.com
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

Mailq and log shows the mail trying to connect directly to *mail.h-email.net* instead of my relay server.

Output of `mailq`:

```
root@webserver:/etc/postfix# mailq
-Queue ID- --Size-- ----Arrival Time---- -Sender/Recipient-------
9F79E60224      382 Thu Jun 25 09:19:49  root@webserver.example.com
         (connect to mail.h-email.net[107.21.213.75]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         tguadagnin@gmail.com

-- 0 Kbytes in 1 Request.
```

Output of mail.log

```
Jun 25 09:20:20 webserver postfix/smtp[6998]: 9F79E60224: to=<tguadagnin@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=31, delays=0.02/0/31/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mail.h-email.net[107.21.213.75]:25: Connection timed out)
```

The log shows `relay=none` while all my other servers with the exact same configuration send email correctly and report as `relay=smtp.example.com` in their logs.

The only difference with this server is that I have it in a different network segment which is one of my DMZ's.

I have placed rules so that the server itself cannot communicate outbound on port 25.
The server can commuicate to the relay host via port 25 successfully.

`dpkg-reconfigure postfix` and setting the system as a *satellite system* does not alleviate the issue.
`mailutils` package provides the `mail` command.

Can anyone help me out? I've been struggling to figure out how to troubleshoot this correctly.

Comment: Some thoughts: Are myhostname = webserver.mydomain and relayhost = smtp.mydomain supposed to be myhostname = webserver.$mydomain and relayhost = smtp.$mydomain ? Either way, are these defined in DNS or just in /etc/hosts? If the latter, smtp_host_lookup = native *may* help.

Comment: Thanks for the response jet it pointed me in the right direction. When I set smtp_host_lookup = native it stopped resolving out to the internet and started reporting relay=smtp.mydomain is not resolvable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears postfix completely ignores `/etc/hosts`.

If the setting `relayhost = FQDN` instead of an IP address, it will try to resolv the FQDN for its IP address and will not use `/etc/hosts` to find it. It will use the system configured `resolv.conf` file if `smtp_host_lookup` is set to native.

Since it could not resolve my relay host it instead just attempted to deliver the mail straight out into the ether. I cannot find details as to if this is the correct behaviour.

Setting the relayhost to an IP address OR ensuring the relayhost FQDN is resolvable WITHOUT using `/etc/hosts` fixes this problem.

Comment: You probably should use square brackets in the relayhost to turn off MX lookup - http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#relayhost

Comment: I have the same issue, `/var/log/mail.info` shows `relay=none`. I tried using directly the IP but that didn't work, I always get `relay=none`. How can I see why it's not using the relay config?

Answer (score 1):

### 1st Option

If you want to relay ALL email to a given `/etc/hosts` host and not receive any email, add this to `/etc/postfix/main.cf` :

`mydestination=                        # Don't deliver anything locally`

`smtp_dns_support_level = disabled     # native lookup only (/etc/hosts)`

`relayhost = hostname.mydomain.tld     # your relay here. add IP/hostname to /etc/hosts`

This will override DNS/MX lookups and use `/etc/hosts` only.
It will never use DNS lookups.

Please note: The lookup is not performed on incoming either. **This is for an outbound (only) server** to a relay that is found in `/etc/hosts`.

*This is appropriate when you want a server to send LOCAL emails (root/cronjobs/etc) to an actual email server for delivery and never receive outside email itself.*

Reference: [smtp_dns_support_level](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_dns_support_level)

---

### 2nd Option

`smtp_host_lookup = native` can be used *in place of*  `smtp_dns_support_level` above.

This will use "native naming service only" aka 'system' lookups.

It will *normally* first query `/etc/hosts` (via [`/etc/nsswitch.conf`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29474/why-does-my-name-resolution-hit-the-dns-even-with-a-hosts-file-entry)*). If not found, it will query a DNS server (default on most system*). In this regard, `/etc/hosts` can still override a lookup.

*This appropriate if your server is also receiving outside email, or needs to use a DNS lookup for anything else not found in `/etc/hosts`. Please note that there is also a `lmtp_host_lookup` option.*

* nsswitch.conf typical example:
`hosts:  files dns` (Queries 'files' (`/etc/hosts`, normally) then the system DNS.)

Reference [smtp_host_lookup](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_host_lookup) , [lmtp_host_lookup](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#lmtp_host_lookup)

Answer (score 0):

I complete resolve same issue with directly connecting to **mail.h-email.net** instead of my relay server.
At that my sendmail try connect to mail.h-email.net independent of my mail destination domain.

My Server hostname = server.domain.org.ua

Incorrect specified relay as IP = 192.168.2.4

I'm sending a test letter to **@ukr.net**, which has nothing to do with mail.h-email.net.

I incorrectly configured relayhost in sendmail by specifying IP-adress instead of hostname_of_relayhost.
Sendmail tries to resolve MX for "IP 192.168.2.4" and unexpectedly receives an existing name "4.org.ua" and MX "mail.h-email.net." for it.

== debug ==

```
= top output =
 sendmail: ./v3LJRuji049269 mail.h-email.net.: user open (sendmail)
 sendmail: ./v3LJhCr0049454 mail.h-email.net.: user open (sendmail)

= # tcpdump -vvv -i wan_if udp =
    server.domain.org.ua.9764 > google-public-dns-b.google.com.domain:  
    MX? 192.168.2.4.org.ua.

    google-public-dns-b.google.com.domain > server.domain.org.ua.9764: 
    q: MX? 192.168.2.4.org.ua. 1/0/1 192.168.2.4.org.ua. [59m59s] MX mail.h-email.net.

    server.domain.org.ua.36133 > google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain: 
     A? mail.h-email.net.

        23:28:28.687538 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 45, id 27064, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 329)
            google-public-dns-a.google.com.domain > server.domain.org.ua.36133: [udp sum ok] 29530 q: A? mail.h-email.net. 16/0/1 mail.h-email.net. [3m28s] A 198.133.159.124, mail.h-email.net. [3m28s] A 198.133.159.123, mail.h-email.net. [3m28s] A 198.133.159.125, mail.h-email.net. [3m28s] A 198.133.159.133, mail.h-email.net. [3m28s] A 198.133.159.137, mail.h-email.net. [3m28s] A 198.133.159.119, mail.h-email.net. [3m28s] A 198.133.159.121, mail.h-email.net. [3m28s] A 198.133.159.122, mail.h-email.net. [3m28s] A 198.133.159.132, mail.h-email.net. [3m28s] A 198.133.159.126, mail.h-email.net. [3m28s] A 198.133.159.139, mail.h-email.net. [3m28s] A 198.133.159.135, mail.h-email.net. [3m28s] A 198.133.159.136, mail.h-email.net. [3m28s] A 198.133.159.120, mail.h-email.net. [3m28s] A 198.133.159.138, mail.h-email.net. [3m28s] A 198.133.159.134 ar: . OPT UDPsize=512 OK (301)

    =check=
    $ nslookup -ty=mx 4.org.ua

    Non-authoritative answer:
    4.org.ua    mail exchanger = 5 mail.h-email.net.
```

So I specify "relay host" as "hostname" and resolve issue.

Answer (score 0):

just found that postfix have/could have its own hosts file /var/spool/postfix/etc/hosts.
I has same issue as reported and with help of "postfix check" command i was able to find this issue. Updated/ added host entry to /var/spool/postfix/etc/hosts and now postfix reads FQDN for hostfile instead of DNS